# Expand a form variable and get the properties

Tags: forms, variables

I have a form and inside the form, I did created a Hash

```
[Array]$Arr_RechercherDep = @(
        @{ 
            Bouton = "$buttonDepDRechercher"
            Texte= "Rechercher à délester"
        }
        @{ 
            Bouton = "$buttonDepDRechercherN"
            Texte  = "Rechercher nouvelle"
        }
    )
```

So what I did put in this hash is the name and the design name of 2 buttons.

So I need to know which button has the focus:

```
foreach ($RechercheDep in $Arr_RechercherDep)
                {
                    If ($($RechercheDep.bouton).focused) { Write-host "$($RechercheDep.bouton) est cliqué." }
                    
                    
                    
                    
            }
```

$RechercheDep.bouton return --> System.Windows.Forms.Button, Text:

If I deffine my hash this way:

```
[Array]$Arr_RechercherDep = @( 
        @{ #Trousse actuelle
            Bouton = "buttonDepDRechercher"
            Texte= "Rechercher à délester"
        }
        @{ 
            Bouton = "buttonDepDRechercherN"
            Texte  = "Rechercher nouvelle"
        }
    )
```

$RechercheDep.bouton will be returning buttonDepDRechercherN
$buttonDepDRechercherN.focused will be returning $false

How may I expand correctly my variable and getting the properties?

Thanks,